# Other than the ESA are there other sources for demographic data?

Tags: game-design, marketing, demographics

I'm pretty interested in seeing demographic data as I find them good targeting tools. But other than the ESA reports (free) and NPD numbers (paid) does anyone know any other sources for such data?

Comment: You might try http://ask.metafilter.com/ for this type of question. I'm not sure this is exactly the right place for this question, but I also can't think of another Stack Exchange site to refer you to.

Comment: Also quite interested in this. It's definitely game-dev relevant, as it feeds directly into design and product development decisions. Also it's very hard to get good information. IndieVision (http://www.indievision.org) has done a lot of good work on trying to pull together numbers, but it's pretty tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a website that has very interesting demographics regarding MMORPG's in the US.
http://www.nickyee.com/daedalus/gateway_intro.html

This is from the same site but it has a bit more general data. Just keep clicking the small "Next Page" link at the bottom for more statistics including Good vs Evil, Choosing a Race, and etc.
http://www.nickyee.com/daedalus/archives/001558.php

Here is a slide show on demographics for teen and adult gameplay in 2009
http://www.pewinternet.org/Presentations/2009/11--Cheats-for-Video-Game-Marketers.aspx

This is another site that has demographic data on game developers which is useful for those developing an SDK or engine. You can also submit a survey to help improve these statistics.
http://archives.igda.org/diversity/report.php

If you are looking for specific demographics you could also try picking up the phone book and calling major players in the game development realm. For example, I am sure Microsoft will have no problem giving you demographics on its specific users. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

These look pretty nice, though I'm not sure:
[Free Demographics](http://www.freedemographics.com/)
[US Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov/main/www/access.html)

EDIT: Also, free.

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but you might want to talk to [EEDAR](http://www.eedar.com/).